# winston logger make logs file by default

Tags: node.js, logging, winston

I just require winston in example.js file like this

```
var winston = require('winston');

//Bla Bla Bla Bla
```

When run this code winston make two files `example.log` and `example_err.log`, i just to know is it default winston behavior or something in my code makes winston act like that?

just in case i don't use any `winston.info` or `winston.error`.

**UPDATE 1**

example.log contains all output of stdout, and example_err.log contains all exception happened in example.js

Comment: Those filenames don't appear in the `winston` package anywhere. The documentation also states _"By default, only the Console transport is set on the default logger"_. So there's something else going on in your situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to add your own transports, like this:

`winston.add(winston.transports.File, { filename: 'somefile.log' });`

You can also search your code and see if you added a transport somewhere, with `winston.add`.

I also suggest checking out the documentation here: https://github.com/winstonjs/winston

Comment: Thanks for answer
But when added `winston.add` make three file `somefile.log`, `example.log` and `example_err.log`

Comment: Have you tried searching your code for all winston.add?